# Updating Database in Laravel 4 with AJAX Data

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I see there are many similar questions out there like this one but none have them have given me exactly what I am looking for.

I have a JQuery sortable list of records. When a user moves a record up or down (so as to re-order the records), JQuery's .ajax() function should take this data and pass it to a Laravel controller function called second(). The function second() should then take that data and, for each row, extract its position (represented by an integer) and update the 'order' column in the database table. The records should then display in that order on the view.

I have everything working up to the point where the data is passed to the second() function:

Route:

```
Route::post( '/income-category/second', array(
  'as' => 'income-category.second',
  'uses' => 'IncomeCategoryController@second'
));
```

JQuery:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update : function () {
        var serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'); //split up each li into an array item
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "income-category/second",
            type: "post",
            data: {serial: serial},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(info){
              console.log(info);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("there's an error with AJAX");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller (incomplete):

```
public function second(){   
    $orders = Input::all();

    foreach($orders as $order){
        $folge[] = $order;  
    }

    return Response::json($folge);
}
```

After some troubleshooting, I finally got the AJAX output to pop up on the console. It turns out that a foreach loop as represented above will throw an "invalid foreach argument" error because - I'm assuming - there is only one key in the following object:

```
Object {serial: "item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=1&item[]=4&item[]=5"}
```

When I have done this in other, non-Laravel projects, a simple foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) worked. Now it does not.

HTML Excerpt:

```
<tbody id="sortable">
      @if(isset($_GET['category']))
          {{ Form::open(array('route'=> array('income-category.update', $_GET['category']), 'method'=>'PUT')) }}
          @foreach($categories as $catId=>$catVal)
            @if($_GET['category'] == $catId)
              <tr id="{{ 'item_'. $_GET['category'] }}">
                <td>{{ Form::text('category_name', $catVal) }} <br>{{ $errors->first('category_name') }}</td>
                <td>
                  {{ Form::submit('Save', ['category'=>$catId, 'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm', 'name' => 'submit_' . $_GET['category'], 'title'=>'Save']) }}&nbsp;
                  {{ link_to('income-category', 'Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-sm', 'title'=>'Cancel']) }}
                </td>
              </tr>
            @else
              <tr>  
                <td>{{ $catVal }}</td>
                <td>{{ HTML::linkAction('IncomeCategoryController@index', '', ['category'=>$catId], ['class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil shadow pointer', 'title'=>'Edit']) }}&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ Form::button('', ['category'=>$catId, 'type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-trash shadow pointer', 'name' => 'delete' . $_GET['category'], 'title'=>'Delete', 'onclick' => 'confirm("For now this is just going to delete no matter what you pick.")']) }} </td>
              </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        {{ Form::close() }}
        ...
        ...
```

I am really confused beyond that so I hope this makes a little sense.

Comment: mmm, so you got an error? what is it ?

Comment: Temporarily change the `type: "post"` to `GET` and also change the route from `Route::post()` to `get(...)` then try again to submit the same thing and check the console, you'll find out a get link there and click that link and you'll get the real error. Once you done then change the `GET` to post again. This is a debugging tip, to find out out the error on server.

Comment: *Or* you can just check the log which Laravel neatly stores inside your `app/storage/logs` folder...

Comment: Could you give us an excerpt from your HTML code?